# Count distinct nodes from traversal in AQL

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am able to get all distinct nodes from a query, but not the count:

```
FOR v in 2..2 OUTBOUND "starting_node" GRAPH "some_graph"
return DISTINCT v._key
```

I want to get only the count of the result. I tried to use [`LENGTH(DISTINCT v._key)`](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Functions/Miscellaneous.html#length) as [suggested in the docs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Examples/Counting.html), but it's not a proper syntax of the AQL:

> syntax error, unexpected DISTINCT modifier near 'DISTINCT v._key)'

The naive solution is to get all keys and count it on the client side, but I am curious how to do it on the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by this blogpost http://jsteemann.github.io/blog/2014/12/12/aql-improvements-for-24/ I prepared the solution using `LET`:

```
LET result = (FOR v in 2..2 OUTBOUND "starting_node" GRAPH "some_graph"
                  return DISTINCT v._key)
RETURN LENGTH(result)
```

It might be not optimal solution, but it works as I expected.

Comment: `LET` can be used, but you may also call `LENGTH()` directly: `RETURN LENGTH(FOR v IN 2..2 OUTBOUND "starting_node" GRAPH "some_graph" RETURN DISTINCT v._key)`

Answer (score 2):

What `RETURN DISTINCT` does is to remove **duplicate values**, but only **after** the traversal.

You can set **traversal options** to eliminate paths **during** the traversal, which can be more efficient especially if you have a highly interconnected graph and a high traversal depth:

```
RETURN LENGTH(
  FOR v IN 2..2 OUTBOUND "starting_node" GRAPH "some_graph"
  OPTIONS { uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true }
    RETURN v._key
)
```

The traversal option `uniqueVertices` can be set to `"global"` so that you don't get the same vertex returned twice from this traversal. The option for *breadth-first search* `bfs` needs to be enabled to use `uniqueVertices: "global"`. The reason why *depth-first search* does not support this uniqueness option is that the result would not be deterministic, hence this combination was disabled.